# Как решить проблему, LINQ ошибка статического метода

Tags: c#, linq

Если `identFixTrip == t.IdentifierTariff = false` то дальше по коду ловлю следующую ошибку здесь -  `t.TariffType.TruckTypes.Select(tt => tt.Id).Contains(shift.TruckType.Id)`

> Для не являющегося статическим метода требуется указать конечный
>   объект

```
tariff = _context.Tariffs.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateStart).Where(t =>
           identFixTrip == t.IdentifierTariff
           && shift.DateDocument >= t.DateStart
           && t.TariffType.TruckTypes.Select(tt => tt.Id).Contains(shift.TruckType.Id)
           && t.TariffType.DeliveryTemperature.Id == deliveryTemperature.Id
       ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Как правильно поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: Вы прям так и пишете `identFixTrip == t.IdentifierTariff = false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор && не даже не проверяет 2 операнд если 1 уже false.

Contains нужно что-то более определенное.

Вместо

```
t.TariffType.TruckTypes.Select(tt => tt.Id).Contains(shift.TruckType.Id)
```

Попробуйте

```
t.TariffType.TruckTypes.Where(tt => TruckType_Id.Contains( tt.Id))
```

Где TruckType_Id заранее подготовленный список id нужного формата. Позже возможно более красивое решение выдам.

Comment: Спасибо за мысль. Сделал так `&& t.TruckTypes.Any(tt => tt.Id == shift.TruckType.Id)` заработало